# Curl of the $E$ field of a moving charge

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, vector-fields

Figure 5.15 from [Purcell: "Electricity & Magnetism" (3rd edition)](https://archive.org/details/ElectricityAndMagnetismPurcell3rdEdition/page/n271/mode/2up?view=theater) shows the electric  field of a uniformly moving charge.

[image: Figure of field of a uniformly moving charge.]

It reads:

> The field in Fig. 5.15 is a field that no stationary charge distribution, whatever its form, could produce. For in this field the line integral of $E$ is in general not zero around a closed path. Consider, for example, the closed path ABCD in Fig. 5.15. The circular arcs contribute nothing to the line integral, being perpendicular to the field; on the radial sections,
> the field is stronger along BC than along DA, so the circulation of $E$ on this path is not zero.

In other words, this is a non conservative field. According to Helmholtz's theorem a non conservative field has a solenoidal field component, i.e. a curl. I wonder how the curl and the curl-free (irrotational) components of this field look like graphically and algebraically.

Comment: [Maxwell-Faraday equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell–Faraday_equation) gives the curl

Comment: The Maxwell-Faraday equation applies to time-varying magnetic fields, which do not exist here.

Comment: A moving point charge has a time-varying magnetic field. You are incorrect. The Maxwell-Faraday equation applies always, as do all of Maxwell’s equations.

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The electric field is given (in Gaussian units) by
${\bf E}
= \frac{q{\bf r}}
{\gamma^2[r^2-({\bf v\times r})^2]^{\frac{3}{2}}}$.
Just take it's curl.
The result is $\nabla\times{\bf E}= \frac{3q({\bf r\times v)(r\cdot v)}}
{\gamma^2[r^2-({\bf v\times r})^2]^{\frac{5}{2}}}$.

Check my algebra.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What formula is this? Do the units of $r$ and $v\times r$ differ?

Comment: The first equation is Eq. {11.154) and Jackson's textbook or (15.51) in my textbook.  The units are the usual units, r in cm and v in cm/sec.

Comment: Ok, I guess then $v \times r$ should be $\frac{v}{c} \times r$.

Comment: I am so used to setting c=1 that I left it out there.